# Fit a boolean condition into the framework of Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

$a=k.B$, where $a$, $B$ (binary), $k$ all are scaler variables.

When $B=0$, $a=0$; and when $B=1$, $a=k$.

$B$ is binary, i.e., $0$ or $1$.

$k$ is $0$ or positive integer, i.e., $0, 1, 2, 3, 4...$

How to decompose it in Linear Programming so that two variables are not in multiplication format?

Is it even possible?

---

As the question is on hold and I got how to do it, I'm posting it here in the question itself. The [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-continuous-and-binary.html) is given in the comment of this question by Erwin Kalvelagen.

$0 \le a \le k_{max}$

$a \le k_{max}.B$

$a \le k$

$a \ge k - k_{max}(1-B)$

Comment: Are $a$, $k$, $B$ scalars, vectors, or matrices?  Are they continuous variables or integer variables (or some of both)?

Comment: 1) Why do you think this issue has something in common with Linear Programming ? On which basis (no intended pun) ? 2) What are the dimensions of $a,B,k$ ? Are $a$ and $k$ **row** vectors ?

Comment: all scalers. **a**, **k** are positive integer (eg: `a=k=4`), **B** is binary (eg: `B=1` or `B=0`)

Comment: Thus you want to express ''$a=k$ OR $a=0$, meaning that you have to implement an "or" condition, whereas Linear Programmign uses a set of conditions connected by (multiple) "and"s. Have a look at (https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12102)

Comment: @JeanMarie that's a helpful link, but the fact that $a$ and $k$ are not binary complicates things.

Comment: `a<=MB` lower limits `a=0` when `B=0`,where `M` is large number (constant). But when `B=1`, how to make `a=k`? Yes it is or conditions, but not in binary.

Comment: See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-continuous-and-binary.html) how to model this with inequalities.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen, the link is a great help. Thank you very much.